# Miller-Rabin Primality Test Often Returns Composite for Prime Numbers

Tags: java, primes, primality-test

I have been trying to implement a Miller-Rabin primality test from scratch (only primitives and Strings) that works for 64 bit integers (longs). I've tried the Java and pseudocode from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Primality_Testing), as well as various other websites. So far, only very small numbers have worked correctly. Most numbers are incorrectly marked composite, such as 53 or 101. I have tried tracking various sections of the code to see where the problem is. It seems to be in the innermost loop. I don't know what the specific issue is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public class PrimeTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PrimeTest app = new PrimeTest();
}

private PrimeTest()
{
    long n = 53; // Change to any number. 53 is prime, but is reported as composite
    if (checkPrime(n, 10))
    {
        System.out.println(n + " is prime.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(n + " is not prime.");
    }
}

// Check if n is prime with 4^(-k) change of error
private boolean checkPrime(long n, int k)
{
    // Factor n-1 as d*2^s
    long d = n - 1;
    int s = 0;
    while (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        d /= 2;
        s++;
    }

    // Repeat k times for 4^-k accuracy
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        long a = (long) ((Math.random() * (n - 3)) + 2);
        long x = modPow(a, d, n);
        if (x == 1 || x == (n - 1))
        {
            continue;
        }
        int r;
        for (r = 0; r < s; r++)
        {
            x = modPow(x, 2, n);
            if (x == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (x == (n - 1))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (r == s)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Return (base^exp) % mod
private long modPow(long base, long exp, long mod)
{
    if (mod == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    long result = 1;
    base = base % mod;
    while (exp > 0)
    {
        if ((exp & 1) == 0)
        {
            result = (result * base) % mod;
        }
        exp = exp >> 1;
        base = (base * base) % mod;
        if (base == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in modPow:

```
if ((exp & 1) == 0)
```

is wrong and should instead be

```
if ((exp & 1) == 1)
```